# If $\lim \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 5$, find $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim \frac{f(x)}{x}$ as $x \to 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital

I don't know the answer to this problem, but I have an attempt.  It's given that the quotient $f(x)/x^2$ has $5$ as a limit.  I cannot apply the quotient rule for limits because I don't know if $\lim f(x)$ exists.  What I do know is that $\lim x^2 = 0$, which clearly is a number.

**An attempt**.  So I can multiply both sides of the hypothesis by $\lim x^2 = 0$ getting

$$\begin{align}
  \lim \frac{f(x)}{x^2} &= 5 \\
  \lim \frac{f(x)}{x^2}\lim x^2 &= 5\lim x^2 \\
  \lim \frac{f(x)}{x^2}x^2 &= 5\lim x^2 \\
  \lim f(x) &= 5\lim x^2 = 0
\end{align}$$

If this is right, then we got the first request.  For the second request, instead of multiplying by $\lim x^2$, we can multiply both sides by $\lim x$, which should give us $\lim f(x)/x = 0$.

**Reference**.  This is problem 56 in section 2.3, Stewart's Calculus, 6th edition.  It's an even number, so I think there's no solution anywhere --- solution's manual nor at the back of the book.

Comment: What's the problem with your attempt?

Comment: Oh, I'm multiplying both sides by zero, making even a false statement true?  I'm not sure.

Comment: @user1145880 You are not multiplying both sides by 0. You are multiplying both sides by a function, and then taking its limiting value. However I think your proof is still incorrect because you are breaking the lefthand limit into a quotient of two limiting function’s and then cancelling it out. This implicitly uses the quotient rule which is only defined when the limit of the denominator is not 0.

Comment: "When the limit of the denominator is not zero"?  That's not specified in Stewart's Calculus 6th edition "Limit Laws", section 2.3, page 77.  The limits need only to exist.

Comment: @user1145880 There is a simple counterexample to see why it is wrong. Consider $\lim\limits_{ x \to 0} x/x$. This should equal 1. But if we use quotient rule then this should equal $\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x} {\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x} = \frac{0}{0}$ which is of indeterminate form.

Comment: @Axo, you're saying that the Limit Laws of Stewart should be making that restriction, right?  I'm inclined to agree with you.

Comment: @user1145880 Yes, in general, the quotient of two functions is well defined only when the denominator function for every point in its domain is non-zero. Here the quotient is not well-defined at $x=0$, which is what the limiting value is, thus we cannot use the quotient rule of limits.

Comment: @Axo Here it's using the product rule, when given $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2$, then find the product $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$. When you mentioned the quotient rule, you might be thinking about the other direction, when given $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2$, then the goal is to find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right to be skeptical about multiplying both sides by zero, it leads to problems sometimes because people then divide by zero without noticing.

Here we don't need to do that though:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} x^2 = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 5\cdot 0 = 0,$$

and the second equality is justified because both limits exist (by the assumption of the exercise). If $\lim f_1(x)$ and $\lim f_2(x)$ exist, then $\lim f_1\cdot f_2$ exists and equals the product $\lim f_1(x)\cdot \lim f_2(x)$.

**Edit to answer comments**

Suppose that for all $x\neq a$ you know that $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ and, moreover, $\lim_{x\to a} f_2(x) = N$. Then you can conclude that $\lim_{x\to a} f_1(x) = N$. This can be checked with the [$\epsilon-\delta$ definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) of the limit.  You don't even need to know that $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ is true for all $x\neq a$, just those "close" to $a$. Say for all $x\in (a-0.1, a+0.1)$ except $a$ itself.

In summary we can perform manipulations on the function before taking the limit without caring about what happens at the limit value. In our case, for all $x\neq 0$, $f(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^2} x^2$ is true. The second of these two functions has a limit at $0$ and we can then say that the first function also has a limit at zero and it equals the limit of the second function.

Comment: When you add the $x^2$ in the denominator of the limiting function, how is that not using the quotient rule of limits?

Comment: The $x^2$s are never 'cancelled out'. You multiply by $1$ cleverly disguised as $x^2/x^2$ and then separate it into two seperate parts which are **multiplying** each other. The quotient rule is never invoked.

Comment: @Axo No, when working "inside" the limit we consider $x$ close to zero, but not zero. For those $x$, $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} x^2 = f(x)$ is an equality. We then use a theorem (the product rule for limits) in the next step.

Comment: @Dosidis, you're multiplying 1 on the right of $\lim f(x)$ and you don't know if that limit exists.  No?

Comment: @Dosidis. My contention is that what you have written shows $\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{ f(x)}{g(x)} \right) $

Comment: @Dosidis, here is why this doesn't work. Let $f(x) = 1$. Then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x) = 1$. But now using your argument let us multiply inside the limit by $\frac{x^2}{x^2}$. Then following your argument, I get, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left( f(x) \cdot \frac{x^2}{x^2} \right)$ $= \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to 0} x^2 = \infty \cdot 0$, which is wrong.

Comment: @ user1145880 @Axo I have edited the answer to explain the argument in a bit more detail. Does the edit cover your questions?

Comment: @Axo excellent example, thank you! The property that allows us to use the theorem is the assumption by the exercise that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exists and equals $5$. Without this the argument fails. In your example this limit does not exists (it equals $+\infty$) and that's exactly why we need to be careful to check the assumptions of the propositions we use.

Comment: @Dosidis I see, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps reversing the chains of equalities will help $0=5\cdot 0= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \lim_{x\to 0} x^2 =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} x^2=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$. Same implications, but reading left to right is perhaps more natural for the implications

Comment: I see it now.  Thank you for the rewrite.  You're only assuming that the problem lets you to.  Great work.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\neq 0$. Then,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{f(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to 0} x^2}{\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)} =0 $$

In contradiction to the fact that this limit must be $\frac{1}{5}$ by the given. A similar claim can be made for $\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

The limit must exist, since $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ is the product of two existing limits.

Comment: Your assumption also includes that the limit exists.  Shouldn't you also assume that it doesn't exist and see what happens?

Comment: That's right, I justified the existence.